# Calculate a vector that lies on plane X and results in vector b when projected onto plane Y.

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

I'm working on a computer program and ran into this problem that I'm struggling to figure out.

Given:

- two planes X and Y that belong to $\mathbf{R^3}$ that both pass through the origin and are defined by perpendicular vectors **x** and **y** respectively
- vector **b** that lies on plane Y

How would you find vector **a** that lies on plane X and results in vector **b** when it is projected onto plane Y?

I tried projecting **b** onto X to find **a**, but I'm pretty sure that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projection of $\mathbf a$ on $Y$ is
$$
\mathbf a - <\mathbf a,\mathbf y>\mathbf y,
$$
so you need a vector $\mathbf a\in X$ that can be written as $\mathbf b + \lambda\mathbf y$ for some $\lambda$. The condition $\mathbf a\in X$ is equivalent to $<\mathbf a, \mathbf x>\, = 0$, so
$$
0 = <\mathbf b + \lambda\mathbf y, \mathbf x> \implies \lambda =-\frac{<\mathbf b , \mathbf x>}{<\mathbf y, \mathbf x>}.
$$
As a consequence,
$$
\mathbf a = \mathbf b  -\frac{<\mathbf b , \mathbf x>}{<\mathbf y, \mathbf x>}\mathbf y
$$

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` instead; the size is more appropriate.

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish I know, was just lazy. I miss my shortcuts

Comment: Use `\newcommand`